# Autodesk Maya 2017 symbol lookup error on start in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, symbolic-link

I've installed Maya 2017 on Ubuntu 20.04, and fixed all start up errors using these commands.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/autodesk/maya2017/lib/libssl.so.10

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so /usr/autodesk/maya2017/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```

When i launch Maya the splash screen appears and closes with the error below.

Warning: COLOR:XML:CATALOG_MANAGER: The shared catalog directory does not exist: /home/kevin/maya/synColor/Shared

Initialized VP2.0 renderer {

Version : 2016.3.78.11. Feature Level 5.

Adapter : GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2

Vendor ID: 4318. Device ID :

Driver : 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.82.

API : OpenGL V.4.6.

Max texture size : 16384 * 16384.

Max tex coords : 32

Shader versions supported (Vertex: 5, Geometry: 5, Pixel 5).

Shader compiler profile : (Best card profile)

Active stereo support available : 0

GPU Memory Limit : 6144 MB.

CPU Memory Limit: 15150.2 MB.

/usr/autodesk/maya2017/bin/maya.bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/autodesk/maya2017/bin/../lib/libOGSDeviceOGL4-16.so: undefined symbol: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init

Answer (score 0):

The commands you quoted for "fixing" the startup errors are unsafe and probably incorrect.

If Maya looks for `/usr/lib/libtiff.so.3` this means that it requires a `libtiff.so` with major version 3 specifically. Symlinking `libtiff.so.5.2.4` which has major version 5 to it may introduce incompatibilities such as missing symbols, because there's no guarantee that different major versions are compatible.

In the same vein, `libssl.so.10` and `libcrypto.so.10` specifically ask for major version 10 of the crypto libraries while `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` are themselves just symlinks to whatever version happens to be installed on your system. You should use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10` instead. If those don't exist you don't have the required version.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. thank you so much.